# How to close the program when it's controlling my mouse and input?

Tags: python, windows, window

My OS: Win 10

I ran this code but mistakenly set a loop that runs 1000 times.

It keeps moving the mouse to that position and input the text.

I want to close it but I can't, so I have to wait until it ends.

**The question is: how to close it?**

```
import os
import time
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import random

posX, posY = # the value I set
for i in range(1000):
    time.sleep(0.01)
    times = random.randint(2,20)
    line = "ha" * times
    pyautogui.click(posX, posY)
    pyperclip.copy(line)
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl","v")
    pyautogui.typewrite("\n")
```

Hope for a practical solution to close the program when it's running.

Comment: Linux? press ctrl-alt-F1 to switch to a text console and then find your process ID and kill it, then press ctrl-alt-F7 to switch back to the GUI. (F keys can be different on some versions of linux, if it doesn't work then try different keys F1 through F8)

Comment: It's windows, not linux

Comment: @user253751 but thanks anyway

Comment: Just hit `Ctrl + C` on the terminal that runs the program. That kills the process. Or you could check for a key press in your program which terminates the loop

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01 But I can't even click that program...

Comment: Are there any other ways like hotkeys?

Comment: As said implement a keypress listener which breaks out of the loop. If you need an example I can provide it

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01 Ok, could you pls provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how you can check for keypresses in a loop and exit if a certain key is pressed

```py
import keyboard


for i in range(1000000):
    print(i)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
        break
```

Once you press the `q` key the loop stops.

This works if each iteration of the loop is fast to execute. If you'd have a longer sleep value and pressed the `q` key it would not be recognized

---

If you have a loop that takes a while for each iteration you can use a listener to achieve the same functionality. Here's an example

```py
from pynput import keyboard
from time import sleep
import signal
import os


def on_press(key):
    try:
        # If key pressed is a special key like shift key.char throws an exception
        if key.char == "q":
            os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
    except AttributeError:
        pass


listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()

for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    sleep(60)
```

I use the pynput module to register a keypress listener. If the key is `q` I kill the process using `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)`. This works even if the loop has long sleep values inside it as you can see in the example.

---

Another method to achieve the same functionality would be to define your own sleep function.

```py
from time import sleep
import keyboard


def interuptable_sleep(seconds):
    accumulator = 0
    while accumulator < seconds:
        accumulator += 0.1
        sleep(0.1)
        if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
            exit()


for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    interuptable_sleep(60)
```

This breaks up the sleep into small fractions and checks whether you pressed the `q` key each time, exiting if you did.

Comment: But how can it be merged into my program?

Comment: Just put the if statement inside your loop

Comment: But I have time.sleep(). Can the if statement be executed?

Comment: Yea it can because your sleep value is so short. So it really doesn't matter. Although if the sleep time gets higher you'll need another solution

Comment: Maybe I need another solution that I can exit whenever I want in the loop, even the sleep value is big.

Comment: @SundayLi I provided two more methods to exit, even with long sleep values, in my answer.